# thread at exit cleanup

Tags: c, multithreading

I have an application in which I have 1 main thread which creates 10 different threads for doing some job. At the end of application, when I try to exit, the application is not able to cleanly exit. The stack trace is not that useful, but its showing the crash in function "cancel_deliver()" My first guess is this is some underlying call made while doing the freeing up of resources used by each thread, but not entirely sure.

fyi: The callback function for each thread has a while (1) loop:

Here is the snippet

```
void main (...)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, xyzCallback,  NULL);
}

void xyzCallback(void* data)
{
    while (1)
    {
       ////
    } 
}

void atExit()
{
    exit(1);
}
```

Is there any thing that I can do to free up resrouces used by my thread and cleanly exit?

Comment: JOIN your threads!

Comment: Show us the code for `cancel_deliver`.

Comment: As far as I know you don't have to join. Exiting with exit() should be fine. My guess is that the problem is elsewhere. What does the threads do? What platform are you targeting? Still, if you can exit the threads, e.g. by returning from the callbacks, it would be interesting to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: The stack trace is showing      ._cancel_deliver is getting called from pthread_self(..), The processing in the spawned thread is completely independent of the main thread. This is currently happening on AIX platform.

Answer (score 3):

**For this case**

If I understand your setup correctly...

One thing you could do is have a set of 'flag' variables, one for each thread (including the main thread). When the main thread is ready to end, set its flag. This flag should be continually checked within the 10 other threads. Once it becomes set, change the flag variable for that specific thread and call `pthread_exit`. In the main exit method, only terminate once all the flag variables are set.

Assuming your program isn't crashing due to another reason, this should enable all the threads to finish in a controlled manner.

(or use `pthread_join` in the main exit function, since `pthread_exit` returns information used by `pthread_join`)

**In general**

Use `pthread_exit` instead of `exit(1)` to cleanly exit the thread.

From the [LLNL](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#CreatingThreads) POSIX Thread Programming page:

> There is a definite problem if main() finishes before the threads it spawned if you don't call pthread_exit() explicitly. All of the threads it created will terminate because main() is done and no longer exists to support the threads.

Also see the pthread_exit [man page](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_exit.txt).

Comment: From the [pthreads_create man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) "_The new thread terminates in one of the following ways: ... Any of the threads in the process calls exit(3), or the main thread performs a return from main(). This causes the termination of all threads in the process_." But it depends on what the threads are doing because that may in turn cause the crash.

Comment: pthread_exit() in the atExit() function will cleanly exit the main thread, but how can I call the pthread_exit() for each spawned threads. Usually, it should be called from the threadCallback function. In my case, I have a while(1) loop, so that won't help. 

In any case, I can still insert pthread_exit for main thread. It shouldnot hurt.

Comment: Agreed. Unusual pthread application... usually you have threads exit on their own and return termination info to main.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether your threads (1) need to end in a well defined way (state), or if the latter does not matter (2) take care where and when they could be cancelled (which happens implicitly when the program ends)

Referring 1: A possible way could be to implement an exit condition which will be triggered when the program shall terminate and makes the threads leave their `while(1)` loop. Before leaving the `main` loop calling `pthread_join()` for any `pthread_t pthread` it received by the calls to `pthread_create()`. If all threads terminate the `main`'s join loops is left and main ends with all threads terminated already.

Referring 2: This is the more critical case, as depending on the thread functions's code it is not clear where it will be canceled, which could lead to unexpected behaviour. A thread could be cancelled at a so called cancellation point. [Some system calls are treated as such](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

In any case the thread function does **not** necessarily need to call `pthread_exit()` as last statement. This is only necessary if you want to have `pthread_join()` receive a pointer passed to `pthread_exit()`.